# Registration process NOT inserting into database

Tags: php, mysql

My `register.inc.php` is not successfully inserting user information into database. However it redirects me to `register_success.php`.

Have I missed something in adding to the inserted data?

**register.inc.php**:

```
include_once 'config.php';
include_once 'db_connect.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'],
        $_POST['firstname'],
        $_POST['lastname'],
        $_POST['home_address1'],
        $_POST['home_address2'],
        $_POST['home_city'],
        $_POST['home_state'],
        $_POST['home_zipcode'],
        $_POST['email'],
        $_POST['p'])) {
// Sanitize and validate the data passed in
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$firstname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRINGS);
$lastname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRINGS);
$home_address1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'home_address1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRINGS);
$home_address2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'home_address2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRINGS);
$home_city = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'home_city', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRINGS);
$home_state = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'home_state', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRINGS);
$home_zipcode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'home_zipcode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRINGS);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Not a valid email
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
}

$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if (strlen($password) != 128) {
    // The hashed pwd should be 128 characters long.
    // If it's not, something really odd has happened
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Invalid password configuration.</p>';
}

// Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
// This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
// breaking these rules.
//

$prep_stmt = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

// check existing email  
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        // A user with this email address already exists
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
                    $stmt->close();
    }
            $stmt->close();
} else {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error Line 39</p>';
            $stmt->close();
}

// check existing username
$prep_stmt = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                    // A user with this username already exists
                    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username already               exists</p>';  
                    $stmt->close();
            }
            $stmt->close();
    } else {
            $error_msg .= '<p class="error">Database error line 55</p>';
            $stmt->close();
    }

// TODO: 
// We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
// rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
// perform the operation.

if (empty($error_msg)) {
    // Create a random salt
    //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE)); // Did not   work
    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

    // Create salted password 
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

    // Insert the new user into the database 
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,
                                                            firstname,
                                                            lastname,
                                                            home_address1,
                                                            home_address2,
                                                            home_city,
                                                            home_state,
                                                            home_zipcode,
                                                            email,
                                                            password,
                                                            salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss', $username, $firstname, $lastname, $home_address1, $home_address2, $home_city, $home_state, $home_zipcode, $email, $password, $random_salt);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ./error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
        }
    }
    header('Location: ./register_success.php');
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, but if you're on PHP 5.3 or later I would suggest using [password_hash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26534575/2370483) instead. Saves you from having to save a separate salt

Comment: what is the error you are recieving?

Comment: +1 for using mysqli and prepared statements

Comment: None with the code the way it is. looking into what errors are being given on the insert.

Answer (score 2):

You use there undefined constant as a third param of `filter_input` function, `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRINGS`.

Correct one is without "s" at the end, `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`.

```
$home_zipcode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'home_zipcode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
//                                                                             ^
etc.
```

Comment: Also, since you're using prepared statements to insert there's no need to sanitize first

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (empty($error_msg)) {
    // Create a random salt
    //$random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16), TRUE)); // Did not   work
    $random_salt = hash('sha512', uniqid(mt_rand(1, mt_getrandmax()), true));

    // Create salted password 
    $password = hash('sha512', $password . $random_salt);

    // Insert the new user into the database 
    if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,
                                                            firstname,
                                                            lastname,
                                                            home_address1,
                                                            home_address2,
                                                            home_city,
                                                            home_state,
                                                            home_zipcode,
                                                            email,
                                                            password,
                                                            salt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param('sssssssssss', $username, $firstname, $lastname, $home_address1, $home_address2, $home_city, $home_state, $home_zipcode, $email, $password, $random_salt);
        // Execute the prepared query.
        $done=$insert_stmt->execute();
        $lines=mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($insert_stmt);
        if($done && $lines==1){
            header('Location: ./register_success.php');
        }
    }
    header('Location: ./error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
  }
}
```

Explain:

> If the statement is UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT, the total number of affected rows can be determined by using the mysqli_stmt_affected_rows() function. Likewise, if the query yields a result set the mysqli_stmt_fetch() function is used.

From PHP Manual, execute function does not confirm the affected row count. So I just rechecked the affected rows, to make sure it would not be headered to success page when no line affected(inserted).

Sorry to failed you, I edited and changed the header codes.

Comment: *"Try this"* - Ok, explain what you did to deserve the upvotes.

Comment: Well, I focused on this sentence, `however it redirects me to register_success.php`. Sorry only covered such simple point.

Comment: I have implemented your changes and it still headers to success page with no insert.

Comment: Sorry, I swapped the two header lines, might you try again for the new. But if you can get the error message, or get the final sql, it would be helpful.